# Grouping label for bar plot in matplotlib python

Tags: python, validation, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am looking for a solution regarding multiple bar chart in python matplotlib library. I want to create a script, which will take a dataset with x values corresponding to following 10 days in each month for 8 months (24 times 10 days, divided to 3 parts of each month: 1, 2 and 3) and born rate of males and females. What I would like to see is a bar chart with males and females born rate for each ten days in each month. The problem is that I don't know how to make a double x axis labeling: first row would be each 10 days: 1,2,3 and below would be name of the month, just like this:

```
| *    @       * males
| *@  *@   @   @ females
| *@  *@  *@ 
-------------- (...)
  1    2   3
     March
```

what I have got till now is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(1,25)

y_males= abs(np.random.normal(100,20,len(x)))
y_females = abs(np.random.normal(50,20,len(x)))


w = 0.3
opacity = 0.8


ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x-w,y_males,w,[enter image description here][1]
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b', align='center',
                 label='Female')
ax.bar(x,y_females,w,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='g',align='center',
                 label='Male')

plt.xticks(x-w/2, ('1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3','1', '2' , '3',))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
ax.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much for your help!
Best,
Dawid

Comment: This is for sure not the first time this is asked. Would you mind looking through other questions first and clearly state in how far this is different?

Comment: The problem is, that I haven't seen anyone producing double x labels where for each 1 row label is the same, repetitive label, and below there is a row with centered label every 3 first row values. I have seen something like this done with panda, but there the 1st row labels were connected to multiple bar charts in single x value, not to multiple.